# basic mathematics c++ code for moving left or moving right for same if condition (k*x<b*k); k =1 or -1

Tags: c++, if-statement, math

Below is a simple program.

```
int main()
{
    int x, b = 3; //size_t x; size_t b = 3;
    
    char const *c = "moving_left"; // "moving_right"
    int k, border;
    
    if (!strcmp(c,"moving_left"))
    {
        k = 1;     // moving left
        border = 0;
        x = 5;
        
    }
    else
    {
        k=-1;     // moving right
        border = 7;
        x = 1;
    }
    

    while(true)
    {
        if (k*x<b*k)
        {
            cerr<<c<<x<<'\n';
            if (x==border){break;}
        }
        x-=k;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm moving left, i.e., x is decreasing, I want to print "moving_left" after x falls behind b (x<b).

And when moving right, i.e., x is increasing, I want to print "moving_right" after x crosses b (x>b).

The above program works fine when x & b are signed integers, but might fail when I declared them as unsigned integers (size_t) because of int promotion (when k = -1).

I want to run the above code in a single while loop for unsigned x & b (I like to declared them as unsigned because they are indices of unmentioned arrays). Also, in the if condition (k*x<b*k), I want left than sign (<).

Multiplying by negative one works only for signed integers. Is there any math trick to make the above code work for unsigned integers with said conditions?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to use unsigned integers here. The ability to represent negative numbers seems like a pretty natural part of what you're modelling here.

Comment: why does it fail with unsigned integers?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it may work or may not work, when I'm moving right, k=-1 so x*k promotes k an unsigned int, a very large number.

Comment: @NathanPierson x, b are indices of two arrays, which are not mentioned the above post, and indices are always unsigned.

Comment: I know, I was rather trying to say that this information is missing in the quesiton. Frankly, I do not understand the question, it seems like you manoeuvred yourself into a situation that cannot work with unsigned, and now you want to use unsigned. The solution seems to be clear, either change the condition or not use unsigned.

Comment: "`if (c == "moving_left")`" is never going to work the way you expect it to.

Comment: When using C-Style character arrays, use `strcmp` to compare the string contents; otherwise you'll be comparing pointers, not contents.

Comment: Since `k` is a multiplier on both sides of the `<` operator, you can factor out the `k` and only compare `(x < b)`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews k is added on purpose, so the same if condition works for both directions, when moving left, k = +1, x<b, the if condition runs as x falls behind b and when moving right k = -1, -x<-b equivalent to x>b, so if condition runs as x exceeds b. This is valid for signed integers (x&b), may not work for unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear why you want to use unsigneds and why you want so much to keep the condition `(k*x<b*k)` rather than something along the line of `if ( (moving_left && x<b) || (!moving_left && b<x)`.

Anyhow if you want to use unsignds and you want to use a single condition for both cases, then you can add a level of indirection:

```
size_t x;
size_t b = 3;

bool move_left = true;
int border;

size_t upper;
size_t lower;

if (move_left) {
    x = 5;
    border = 0;
    upper = b;
    lower = x;        
} else {
    x = 1;
    border = 0;
    upper = x;
    lower = b;
}
    
while(true) {
    if (lower < upper) {
        std::cerr<<x<<'\n';
        if (x==border){break;}
    }
    x-=k;
}
```